# Triggering a method from one class to an other using a button in Android SDK

Tags: java, android, events, event-delegation

I'm sorry if this is asked too much but I couldn't find something clear enough.

I'm developing a little game engine for android.
I've already implemented a gamepad class to control the touch screen.
The game pad class draws an analog stick if someone touches the right area and also draws to buttons on the side.

The problem is , making it simple, i have the main class GAME that as the LEVEL class and GAMEPAD class.

Inside the GAMEPAD code i can trigger things when someone pressed\releases a button.
The problem is I wan't to trigger something to the main  GAME class by pushing a button witch is handled in the GAMEPAD class.

In C# i would use events and delegated.

In Java i have no clue.. i want the gpad to invoke a method to who is registered.

This is what i'm hoping to achieve on the main GAME class.

.. void onGpadClick (e EventArgument)
{
 if (e.Button==Button.A&&e.ButtonState==ButtonState.Pressed) Shoot();

}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Intents.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is this:

1. Let your GAMEPAD-class recieve an instance GAME-class (either in its constructor or by a set-method)
2. In your GAME-class, you add methods containing what ever you want done for each button e.g. `onButtonAClicked()`, `onButtonBClicked()` and `onPadClicked()`. (If those are the options - add more if you have more options).
3. Detect the clicks from your GAMEPAD-class by setting a OnClickListener on each button e.g. `buttonA.setOnClicklistner( new OnClickListener() { //override the onClick-method here } )` Then override the onClick-method and add your implementation there e.g. `myGame.onButtonAClicked()`.

Hope it helps.